# Align button inline with inputs (with bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with bootstrap classes col-lg-x to build two inline inputs and a filter button.

I can't align button with any class joined to form-groups/form-control bootstrap classes.

```
<form method="POST" action="example.com" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<div class="form-group col-lg-3">
    <label for="pedido">Pedido:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="pedido" type="text" id="pedido">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-3">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="email" type="text" id="email">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-1">
    <input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" value="Filtrar">
</div>
</form>
```

When I add `height: 60px` - the height other inputs have - I get the same content height as them. But can't find a way to align at bottom.

Comment: how do you want to align them exactly? Did you want the boxes to align horizontally?

Comment: use this https://jsfiddle.net/1mrhrzLn/ and show what you are trying to do

Comment: Yes @Keith, that's it. Align with boxes horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `top: 18px;` applied to a class on the button's `<div>` or the button itself.

Another option would be to utilize Bootstrap 4 and it's row-eq-height class as a helper for aligning your elements. [PEN HERE](http://codepen.io/illdapt/pen/ozkxLb)

Comment: I applied `top: 25px` for button gets perfectly aligned with input boxes. Would be great if I could use something less hard coded, but it's ok. Thanks!

Comment: Padding on the button would also be another option. With that, you could set it to a percentage making it a bit more versitle. I would recommend you tie together all of these form-item `<div>`'s into a main "parent" div as well, allowing them to be styled/moved together as well. Glad it works for your application needs for now.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you're trying to inline these fields. You can use the placeholder instead of a label to save room.

https://jsfiddle.net/1mrhrzLn/1/

```
<form method="POST" action="example.com" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<div class="form-group col-lg-3">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Pedido" name="pedido" type="text" id="pedido">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-3">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" type="text" id="email">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-1">
    <input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" value="Filtrar">
</div>
</form>

div.form-group {
  margin: 0px auto;
}

div.form-group .form-control {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 1%;
}
```